# how to get selected list options from Angular Material select List and send it as Json array

Tags: angular, angular-material

[image: This is my console.log]

I am using angular material selection list. Below is my Console log. I want to get all the selected options and all the unselected options. I want to send both in as single JSON array.

```
  <mat-selection-list #list (selectionChange)="onChangeYuvak($event)">
      <mat-list-option *ngFor="let yuvak of yuvaks"
      (click)="onAreaListControlChanged(list)"
      class="mt-1" [value]="yuvak.user_id">
        <nb-user name="{{yuvak.cnt_first_name + ' ' + yuvak.cnt_last_name}}" size="large" title="{{yuvak.cnt_mobile_no}}"
          picture="{{yuvak.profile_picture}}">
        </nb-user>
        <img matListAvatar src="{{yuvak.profile_picture}}" alt="...">
      </mat-list-option>
    </mat-selection-list>
```

This is my ts files

```
onChangeYuvak($event) {
    console.log($event);
    console.log($event.option.selectionList.selectedOptions.selected.values);
    this.selectedList = $event.option.selectionList.selectedOptions.selected;
    console.log(this.selectedList)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` of Javascript Array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map.

Code example: `this.shoesSelectionList.selectedOptions.selected.map(s => s.value)`

With this, implement a difference handler to take out the unselected.

See my demo StackBlitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-selection-list-demo1?file=app/list-selection-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

To get selected options you can simply use `{{list.selectedOptions.selected}}` and if you want all the options then you can use `{{list.options}}`.

To iterate over array and perform operations you can use `.map()` javascript function